# Select statement to display correct value between 2 tables

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables :

Tbl_PCode:

```
ID : 54321
Date : 8/1/2016
PCode: REG 
Hours: 8

ID : 54321
Date : 8/1/2016
PCode: OT 
Hours: 2
```

Tbl_TCode:

```
ID : 54321
Date : 8/1/2016
TCode: InsideC 
Hours: 6

ID : 54321
Date : 8/1/2016
TCode: OutsideC 
Hours: 4
```

Need to display:

```
ID  PCode   Hours   TCode

54321 REG   6   InsideC
54321 REG   2   OutsideC
54321 OT    2   OutsideC
```

Please help witht the SQL statement.

Comment: you know, you *can* explain what are the rules to join those tables. Otherwise we will be just guessing

Comment: Need to display:

ID PCode Hours TCode

54321 REG 6 InsideC 54321 REG 2 OutsideC 54321 OT 2 OutsideC

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Yes, you already showed what you need to display. Yet you haven't explained the rules behind your desired result. Otherwise, an answer could be: `SELECT 54321 ID, 'REG' PCode, 6 [Hours], 'InsideC' TCode
UNION ALL
SELECT 54321 ID, 'REG' PCode, 2 [Hours], 'OutsideC' TCode
UNION ALL
SELECT 54321 ID, 'OT' PCode, 2 [Hours], 'OutsideC' TCode`

Comment: I can see `8 + 2 hours = 6 + 4 hours` but what are the rules of who go first? and what db version are you using

Comment: I would like to split up a transaction with values from tbl_PCode first. Please advise the select statement. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDavis Please just at least **try** to explain what do you mean with `I would like to split up a transaction with values from tbl_PCode first`. You can't just say "I want this result" with no explanation whatsoever about how do you get those results

Comment: @Lamak I will first look at total REG hours for the day and then compare with InsideC hours (6) since 6 is less than 8 I will display 6 hours first and then add the remaining 8-6 = 2 hrs on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right. Added `pos` column to introduce order of rows.

```
with 
-- sample data
Tbl_PCode as (
    select * 
    from (values 
           (54321,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'REG', 8, 1),
           (54321,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'OT', 2, 2)
           ) t(ID,Date,PCode,Hours,pos) 
), 
Tbl_TCode as (
    select * 
    from (values 
           (54321,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'InsideC', 6, 1),
           (54321,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'OutsideC', 4, 2)
           ) t(ID,Date,TCode,Hours,pos)

), 
tally as ( 
     select top(24) rn= row_number() over(order by (select null))
     from sys.all_objects
),
-- query
t_P as (
    select *, rn=row_number() over(partition by ID,Date order by pos)  
    from Tbl_PCode
    cross apply (select top(Hours) 1 n 
                 from tally
                ) x
), 
t_T as (
    select *, rn=row_number() over(partition by ID,Date order by pos)  
    from Tbl_TCode
    cross apply (select top(Hours) 1 n 
                 from tally
                ) x
)
select t_P.ID, t_P.Date, t_P.PCode, count(*), t_T.TCode
from t_P
join t_T on t_P.ID=t_T.ID and t_P.Date=t_T.Date and t_P.rn=t_T.rn
group by t_P.ID, t_P.Date, t_P.PCode, t_T.TCode
```

Comment: Thank you. We have changed the request - the date column is removed.  Please note the 2 tables:      Table PCodePERSONNUM PAYCODE HOURS
100444 REG 8
100444 OTC 2
700000 REG 40
700000 OTC 2
Next table: Tbl_TransferCodePERSONNUM TRANSFERCODE HOURS
100444 Outside 4
100444 Inside 6
700000 Inside 20
700000 Outside 22

Comment: Output should look like: PERSONNUM PAYCODE HOURS TRANSFERCODE
100444 REG 6 Inside
100444 REG 2 Outside
100444 OTC 2 Outside
700000 REG 22 Outside
700000 REG 18 Inside
700000 REG 2 Inside

Comment: tblPCode: ID : 54321
PCode: REG 
Hours: 8

ID : 54321
PCode: OT 
Hours: 2

Comment: Please edit your question to show new request or ask another one.

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your help. The challenge I now have is that the Hours are now decimals. Can you please help.

Comment: Here is the entire SQL Code for your review.